# Hibernate query stopped working after switching to maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I wanted an easier way to manage libraries so I decided to work on adding maven to my project. Basically copied the code into the folders, added all the cfg and hbm files to the resources folder. My project was working as intended before maven with the same code. I even reverted back from Hibernate 5.0 to 4.2 to try and solve the problem. It appears to be a mapping problem, I get the following error on start:

```
01:21:49.184 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from where (inplay=true )and(bin<30 ) order by  bin ASC' at line 1
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2116)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:957)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:226)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
at dao.TicketDAO.get30Tickets(TicketDAO.java:88)
at gui.SellingMain.reloadGameButtons(SellingMain.java:98)
at gui.SellingMain.<init>(SellingMain.java:78)
at gui.SellingMain$39.run(SellingMain.java:2029)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

The code:

```
public List<Tickets> get30Tickets(){
    List ts = new ArrayList<Tickets>();
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
        trns = session.beginTransaction();
        ts = session.createQuery("from Tickets as t where t.inplay = true and t.bin < 30 ORDER BY t.bin ASC").list();

    } catch (RuntimeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        releaseResources();
    }
    return ts;
}
```

tickets entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 11, 2015 7:57:00 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entity.Tickets" table="tickets" catalog="fire_tickets" optimistic-lock="version">
        <composite-id name="id" class="entity.TicketsId">
            <key-property name="serial" type="string">
                <column name="Serial" length="12" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="gameTemplatesPartNum" type="string">
                <column name="game_templates_part_num" length="12" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="datePlaced" type="date">
            <column name="Date_placed" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateRemoved" type="date">
            <column name="Date_removed" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="unsoldAmt" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Unsold_amt" />
        </property>
        <property name="actualGross" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Actual_gross" />
        </property>
        <property name="actualPrizes" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Actual_prizes" />
        </property>
        <property name="actualNet" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Actual_net" />
        </property>
        <property name="bin" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Bin" />
        </property>
        <property name="inplay" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="Inplay" />
        </property>
        <property name="closed" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Closed" />
        </property>
        <property name="unsoldTickets" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Unsold_tickets" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastSaleRem" type="java.lang.Byte">
            <column name="Last_sale_rem" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem1" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem1" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem2" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem2" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem3" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem3" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem4" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem4" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem5" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem5" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem6" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem6" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem7" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem7" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem8" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem8" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem9" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem9" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem10" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem10" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem11" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem11" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem12" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem12" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem13" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem13" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem14" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem14" />
        </property>
        <property name="prizeRem15" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Prize_rem15" />
        </property>
        <property name="datePurch" type="date">
            <column name="date_purch" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="invoiceNum" type="string">
            <column name="invoice_num" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="type" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="type" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/fire_tickets</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">-</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">-</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>

    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>
    <mapping resource="entity/Users.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/SaleSessions.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/GameTemplates.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/MfgId.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/Customers.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/BigWinners.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/Locations.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/Sessions.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/TillTape.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/DistsId.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="entity/Tickets.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Tickets.java

```
    package entity;
// Generated Oct 11, 2015 7:56:58 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Tickets generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="tickets"
    ,catalog="fire_tickets"
    , uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="Serial") 
)
public class Tickets  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private TicketsId id;
     private Date datePlaced;
     private Date dateRemoved;
     private Integer unsoldAmt;
     private Integer actualGross;
     private Integer actualPrizes;
     private Integer actualNet;
     private Integer bin;
     private Boolean inplay;
     private Integer closed;
     private Integer unsoldTickets;
     private Byte lastSaleRem;
     private Integer prizeRem1;
     private Integer prizeRem2;
     private Integer prizeRem3;
     private Integer prizeRem4;
     private Integer prizeRem5;
     private Integer prizeRem6;
     private Integer prizeRem7;
     private Integer prizeRem8;
     private Integer prizeRem9;
     private Integer prizeRem10;
     private Integer prizeRem11;
     private Integer prizeRem12;
     private Integer prizeRem13;
     private Integer prizeRem14;
     private Integer prizeRem15;
     private Date datePurch;
     private String invoiceNum;
     private Integer type;

    public Tickets() {
    }


    public Tickets(TicketsId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Tickets(TicketsId id, Date datePlaced, Date dateRemoved, Integer unsoldAmt, Integer actualGross, Integer actualPrizes, Integer actualNet, Integer bin, Boolean inplay, Integer closed, Integer unsoldTickets, Byte lastSaleRem, Integer prizeRem1, Integer prizeRem2, Integer prizeRem3, Integer prizeRem4, Integer prizeRem5, Integer prizeRem6, Integer prizeRem7, Integer prizeRem8, Integer prizeRem9, Integer prizeRem10, Integer prizeRem11, Integer prizeRem12, Integer prizeRem13, Integer prizeRem14, Integer prizeRem15, Date datePurch, String invoiceNum, Integer type) {
       this.id = id;
       this.datePlaced = datePlaced;
       this.dateRemoved = dateRemoved;
       this.unsoldAmt = unsoldAmt;
       this.actualGross = actualGross;
       this.actualPrizes = actualPrizes;
       this.actualNet = actualNet;
       this.bin = bin;
       this.inplay = inplay;
       this.closed = closed;
       this.unsoldTickets = unsoldTickets;
       this.lastSaleRem = lastSaleRem;
       this.prizeRem1 = prizeRem1;
       this.prizeRem2 = prizeRem2;
       this.prizeRem3 = prizeRem3;
       this.prizeRem4 = prizeRem4;
       this.prizeRem5 = prizeRem5;
       this.prizeRem6 = prizeRem6;
       this.prizeRem7 = prizeRem7;
       this.prizeRem8 = prizeRem8;
       this.prizeRem9 = prizeRem9;
       this.prizeRem10 = prizeRem10;
       this.prizeRem11 = prizeRem11;
       this.prizeRem12 = prizeRem12;
       this.prizeRem13 = prizeRem13;
       this.prizeRem14 = prizeRem14;
       this.prizeRem15 = prizeRem15;
       this.datePurch = datePurch;
       this.invoiceNum = invoiceNum;
       this.type = type;
    }

     @EmbeddedId


    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="serial", column=@Column(name="Serial", unique=true, nullable=false, length=12) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="gameTemplatesPartNum", column=@Column(name="game_templates_part_num", nullable=false, length=12) ) } )
    public TicketsId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(TicketsId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="Date_placed", length=10)
    public Date getDatePlaced() {
        return this.datePlaced;
    }

    public void setDatePlaced(Date datePlaced) {
        this.datePlaced = datePlaced;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="Date_removed", length=10)
    public Date getDateRemoved() {
        return this.dateRemoved;
    }

    public void setDateRemoved(Date dateRemoved) {
        this.dateRemoved = dateRemoved;
    }


    @Column(name="Unsold_amt")
    public Integer getUnsoldAmt() {
        return this.unsoldAmt;
    }

    public void setUnsoldAmt(Integer unsoldAmt) {
        this.unsoldAmt = unsoldAmt;
    }


    @Column(name="Actual_gross")
    public Integer getActualGross() {
        return this.actualGross;
    }

    public void setActualGross(Integer actualGross) {
        this.actualGross = actualGross;
    }


    @Column(name="Actual_prizes")
    public Integer getActualPrizes() {
        return this.actualPrizes;
    }

    public void setActualPrizes(Integer actualPrizes) {
        this.actualPrizes = actualPrizes;
    }


    @Column(name="Actual_net")
    public Integer getActualNet() {
        return this.actualNet;
    }

    public void setActualNet(Integer actualNet) {
        this.actualNet = actualNet;
    }


    @Column(name="Bin")
    public Integer getBin() {
        return this.bin;
    }

    public void setBin(Integer bin) {
        this.bin = bin;
    }


    @Column(name="Inplay")
    public Boolean getInplay() {
        return this.inplay;
    }

    public void setInplay(Boolean inplay) {
        this.inplay = inplay;
    }


    @Column(name="Closed")
    public Integer getClosed() {
        return this.closed;
    }

    public void setClosed(Integer closed) {
        this.closed = closed;
    }


    @Column(name="Unsold_tickets")
    public Integer getUnsoldTickets() {
        return this.unsoldTickets;
    }

    public void setUnsoldTickets(Integer unsoldTickets) {
        this.unsoldTickets = unsoldTickets;
    }


    @Column(name="Last_sale_rem")
    public Byte getLastSaleRem() {
        return this.lastSaleRem;
    }

    public void setLastSaleRem(Byte lastSaleRem) {
        this.lastSaleRem = lastSaleRem;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem1")
    public Integer getPrizeRem1() {
        return this.prizeRem1;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem1(Integer prizeRem1) {
        this.prizeRem1 = prizeRem1;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem2")
    public Integer getPrizeRem2() {
        return this.prizeRem2;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem2(Integer prizeRem2) {
        this.prizeRem2 = prizeRem2;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem3")
    public Integer getPrizeRem3() {
        return this.prizeRem3;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem3(Integer prizeRem3) {
        this.prizeRem3 = prizeRem3;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem4")
    public Integer getPrizeRem4() {
        return this.prizeRem4;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem4(Integer prizeRem4) {
        this.prizeRem4 = prizeRem4;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem5")
    public Integer getPrizeRem5() {
        return this.prizeRem5;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem5(Integer prizeRem5) {
        this.prizeRem5 = prizeRem5;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem6")
    public Integer getPrizeRem6() {
        return this.prizeRem6;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem6(Integer prizeRem6) {
        this.prizeRem6 = prizeRem6;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem7")
    public Integer getPrizeRem7() {
        return this.prizeRem7;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem7(Integer prizeRem7) {
        this.prizeRem7 = prizeRem7;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem8")
    public Integer getPrizeRem8() {
        return this.prizeRem8;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem8(Integer prizeRem8) {
        this.prizeRem8 = prizeRem8;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem9")
    public Integer getPrizeRem9() {
        return this.prizeRem9;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem9(Integer prizeRem9) {
        this.prizeRem9 = prizeRem9;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem10")
    public Integer getPrizeRem10() {
        return this.prizeRem10;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem10(Integer prizeRem10) {
        this.prizeRem10 = prizeRem10;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem11")
    public Integer getPrizeRem11() {
        return this.prizeRem11;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem11(Integer prizeRem11) {
        this.prizeRem11 = prizeRem11;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem12")
    public Integer getPrizeRem12() {
        return this.prizeRem12;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem12(Integer prizeRem12) {
        this.prizeRem12 = prizeRem12;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem13")
    public Integer getPrizeRem13() {
        return this.prizeRem13;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem13(Integer prizeRem13) {
        this.prizeRem13 = prizeRem13;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem14")
    public Integer getPrizeRem14() {
        return this.prizeRem14;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem14(Integer prizeRem14) {
        this.prizeRem14 = prizeRem14;
    }


    @Column(name="Prize_rem15")
    public Integer getPrizeRem15() {
        return this.prizeRem15;
    }

    public void setPrizeRem15(Integer prizeRem15) {
        this.prizeRem15 = prizeRem15;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_purch", length=10)
    public Date getDatePurch() {
        return this.datePurch;
    }

    public void setDatePurch(Date datePurch) {
        this.datePurch = datePurch;
    }


    @Column(name="invoice_num", length=10)
    public String getInvoiceNum() {
        return this.invoiceNum;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNum(String invoiceNum) {
        this.invoiceNum = invoiceNum;
    }


    @Column(name="type")
    public Integer getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }




}
```

Comment: can you shouw your Tickets entity?

Comment: Ary you sure that this query is the problem?

Comment: @Jens added entity, this is the first query that is executed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you adding `hibernate.query.factory_class` property in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file??

Comment: @NewBeeDeveloper Hibernate is still very new to me, the example I followed when I setup everything included that. My program worked fine until I try to use Maven. Should it be left out completely or moved?

Comment: @Switcher05, just remove that property and check whether your query is working or not..

Comment: @NewBeeDeveloper Doesn't work but gives new error of Tickets not being mapped. org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Tickets is not mapped [from Tickets where inplay = true and bin < 30 ORDER BY bin ASC]

Comment: @Switcher05, U missed hbm2ddl property in your cfg file...

Answer (score 0):

The query where there is a syntax error looks different in the log than in the code.

It is possible that since you switched to maven your project is not compiling, and when you start your server, Eclipse (I assume) just deploy the last successfull build ".class"

Check if you have no error in your pom (esclamation mark) and try to clean everything.

Comment: Using intellij 15. When I removed the hibernate.query.factory_class I get the following stacktrace: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Tickets is not mapped [from Tickets where inplay = true and bin < 30 ORDER BY bin ASC] Which is the correct query and now identifies Tickets as a table but it is no longer mapped.